# How do I achieve Python TCP Socket Client/Server × JSON?

Tags: python, json, sockets, server, tcp

*Backstory: what I have done*

`{Codes at the bottom}` I've already coded the multithreaded client and server programs using python socket, with the help of the following sites:

> [I. Echo Client and Server](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#echo-client-and-server)
>
> [II. Socket Server with Multiple Clients | Multithreading | Python](https://codezup.com/socket-server-with-multiple-clients-model-multithreading-python/)
>
> [III. Python Socket Receive Large Amount of Data](http://%20https://newbedev.com/python-socket-receive-large-amount-of-data)

### **Regarding JSON**

Now I've been told to make the data format JSON and given my stupidity, I still don't understand how even after reading sites that frequently claim it's super easy.

> **(1)** I learnt that JSON is for "serializing and transmitting data between a server and web applications", but I am still perplexed by this. *So genuinely asking, what's the point in using JSON and what are the consequences of not using JSON format here?*
>
> **(2) And most importantly, exactly at what line in my codes should I turn the messages into JSON format, *and how?*** At what line and how should I unJSON the messages?

### **My Codes Currently**

*_server.py*

```
    import socket
    import os
    from _thread import *
    import struct # Here to convert Python data types into byte streams (in string) and back
    
    # ---- To Avoid Message Boundary Problem on top of TCP protocol ----
    def send_msg(sock: socket, msg):  # ---- Use this to send
        # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
        msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
        sock.sendall(msg)
    
    def recv_msg(sock: socket):       # ---- Use this to receive
        # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
        raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
        if not raw_msglen:
            return None
        msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
        # Read the message data
        return recvall(sock, msglen)
    
    def recvall(sock: socket, n: int):
        # Helper function to receive n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
        data = bytearray()
        while len(data) < n:
            packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
            if not packet:
                return None
            data.extend(packet)
        return data
    
    # ---- Server Communication Setup
    
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
    PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
    ThreadCount = 0
    
    try: # create socket
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        print ("Socket successfully created")
    except socket.error as err:
        print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))
    
    try: # bind socket to an address
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    
    print('Waitiing for a Connection..')
    s.listen(3)
    
    def threaded_client(conn: socket):
        conn.send(str.encode('Welcome to the Server'))
        while True:
            # data = conn.recv(2048) # receive message from client
            data = recv_msg(conn)
            reply = 'Server Says: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            # conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
            send_msg(conn, str.encode(reply))
        conn.close()
    
    while True:
        Client, addr = s.accept()
        print('Connected to: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (Client, )) # Calling threaded_client() on a new thread
        ThreadCount += 1
        print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))
    s.close()
```

*_client.py*

```
import socket
import struct # Here to convert Python data types into byte streams (in string) and back 

# ---- To Avoid Message Boundary Problem on top of TCP protocol ----
def send_msg(sock: socket, msg):  # ---- Use this to send
    # Prefix each message with a 4-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>I', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)

def recv_msg(sock: socket):       # ---- Use this to receive
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msglen = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not raw_msglen:
        return None
    msglen = struct.unpack('>I', raw_msglen)[0]
    # Read the message data
    return recvall(sock, msglen)

def recvall(sock: socket, n: int):
    # Helper function to receive n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data

# ---- Client Communication Setup ----

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print ("Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

print('Waiting for connection')
try:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

Response = s.recv(1024)
while True:
    Input = input('Say Something: ')
    # s.send(str.encode(Input))
    send_msg(s, str.encode(Input))
    # Response = s.recv(1024)
    Response = recv_msg(s)
    print(Response.decode('utf-8'))

s.close()
```

Comment: I think the main point is that you don't understand the task since you don't understand what JSON is. JSON is a string representation of structured data. So the point is to start with structured data first - which you don't do in your question. Given that you don't have structured data in the first place you also fail to understand why you should use JSON for your (unstructured) data)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich True. I don't understand the need for it at all so that's why I'm desperate to find out its purpose when I was told to use JSON here but that was the only instruction I had. In the future, the task should evolve to the server distributing items to the clients as they ask for them, while at this point, my task is to realize the communication through text messages between a server and multiple clients. So my current doubts are: 1. Do I really need JSON for this one? (I think not cuz you pointed out I got only unstructured data), 2. If I have to use JSON, how scan I apply it? Thx

Comment: If you have unstructured data (as you currently do) you don't need JSON. If you have structured data (lists, tuples, dictionaries. ..) just serialize it into JSON before using your code to send it and then deserialize it after you received it completely.